# ¿Cómo solucionar el error: "importError the appdirs package is required" al usar cx_freeze?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

Estoy tratando de convertir un script .pyw a .exe.
Estuve buscando como hacerlo y encontré una biblioteca llamada cx_freeze
Ya me saltaron otros errores relacionados con tcl, pero esos ya los solucioné.

Ahora, al ejecutar el .exe me da el siguiente error:

ImportError: The 'appdirs' package is required; normally this is bundled with this package so if you get this warning, consult the packager of your distribution

Revise el foro en su versión en inglés, pero ninguna de las soluciones me sirvió.

Este es el código del setup:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os  

if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

ejecutables = [Executable( 
    "HardGame.pyw", 
    base = base, 
    targetName = "HardGame.exe")]

    os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tcl8.6'
    os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'C:\Users\Carlos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tcl\tk8.6'

    setup(
        name = "HardGame",#El nombre de tu aplicación
        version = "2.0",
        options = {
            "build_exe":{
                "include_files":["assets/","tcl86t.dll", "tk86t.dll"],
                "packages": ["pygame","sys","os",
                "configparser","pygame.locals",
                "numbers","tendo","tkinter"]}},
        executables = ejecutables
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Bien ese error se da por que no logra encontrar la carpeta tcl/tck o tkinter, hasta donde recuerdo,
trata de ingresar estas lineas de codigo

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
import sys
import six
import packaging
import packaging.version
import packaging.specifiers
import os
import os.path
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
```

Comment: Me salta un error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'